# Como obtener un objeto evaluando al padre e hijos y nietos, en una lista linq

Tags: c#, .net, linq

hola estoy teniendo problemas con evaluar un objeto que tiene hijos y nietos, el caso es que tengo una lista de promos de tipo ProductoResumen, dentro del promo tipo ProductoResumen, tengo una propiedad llamada PromocionID, productoID y una lista de ProductosPromos.. dentro del objeto productosPromos, tengo una propiedad llamada productoId y una lista de modificadoresCantidad de tipo ModificadorCantidad.

las clases
//

```
 public class ProductoResumen
    {
        public ProductoResumen()
        {          
            this.ModificadorCantidadLista = new List<ModificadorCantidad>();
            this.ProductosPromos = new List<ProductoPromo>();
        }

        public float Importe
        {
            get
            {
                return this.Cantidad * this.PrecioItem;
            }
        }

        public int REGJMPMD_ID { get; set; }

        public Guid GrupoID { get; set; }

        public bool EsAgrupado { get; set; }

        public int PromocionID { get; set; }

        public string PromocionNombre { get; set; }

        public int? ModificadorID { get; set; }

        public int? ProductoID { get; set; }

        public int Cantidad { get; set; }

        public string Comentario { get; set; }

        public float Precio { get; set; }
        public float SoloPrecio { get; set; }

        public float PrecioItem { get; set; }

        public bool TieneModificadores { get; set; }

        public string PrecioTexto
        {
            get
            {
                return this.Precio.ToString("c");
            }
        }

        public string SoloPrecioTexto
        {
            get
            {
                return this.SoloPrecio.ToString("c");
            }
        }

       
        public string ProductoNombre { get; set; }

        public List<jmpm_mesaprodmod> RegistrosLista { get; set; }

        public int MesaID { get; set; }

        public int? AutorizacionID { get; set; }
        public string Hash { get; set; }

        public bool EsPromocion
        {
            get
            {
                return this.PromocionID != 0;
            }
        }


        public List<ProductoPromo> ProductosPromos { get; set; }

        public List<ProductoResumen> ProductoEnPromocion { get; set; }

        public List<ModificadorCantidad> ModificadorCantidadLista { get; set; }

        public string Impresora { get; set; }

        public string UsuarioNombre { get; set; }

        public DateTime Fecha { get; set; }

       

        public int Comensal { get; set; }

        public int GrupoOriginal { get; set; }
    }
     
    public class ProductoPromo
    {
        public ProductoPromo()
        {
            this.ModificadorCantidadLista = new List<ModificadorCantidad>();
        }

        public int Regjmpm_MesaID { get; set; }
        public int Regjmpm_ID { get; set; }
        public bool EsAgrupado { get; set; }
        public int PromocionID { get; set; }
        public string Producto { get; set; }
        public int? ProductoID { get; set; }
        public int Regjmpm_Grupo { get; set; }
        public int Regjmpm_Comensal { get; set; }
        public int Cantidad { get; set; }
        public string Comentario { get; set; }
        public float PrecioProducto { get; set; }
        public float PromocionPrecio { get; set; }
        public float SoloPrecio { get; set; }
        public float PrecioItem { get; set; }
        public bool TieneModificadores { get; set; }
        public string PrecioTexto
        {
            get
            {
                return this.PrecioProducto.ToString("c");
            }
        }

        public string ProductoNombre { get; set; }

        public bool EsPromocion
        {
            get
            {
                return this.PromocionID != 0;
            }
        }
        public List<ModificadorCantidad> ModificadorCantidadLista { get; set; }

    }

    public class ModificadorCantidad
    {
        public int REGJMPMD_MesaID { get; set; }
        public int JMPM_MesaID { get; set; }
        public int JMPMD_ID { get; set; }
        public int JMPMD_MesaProdModID { get; set; }
        public int ModificadorID { get; set; }
        public int Cantidad { get; set; }
        public string Modificador { get; set; }
        public float Precio { get; set; }
        public int Regjmpm_ID { get; set; }
        public int ProductoID { get; set; }
        public int JMPM_PromocionID { get; set; }
        public int Regjmpm_MesaID { get; set; }

        public float Importe
        {
            get
            {
                return this.Cantidad * Precio;
            }
        }
    }
```

lo que estoy tratando de hacer es incrementer la cantidad de cada uno de los objetos si tienen por lo menos similitudes con un objeto de la lista promos.
evaluando PromocionID, productoID en ProductoResumen, ProductoID en ProductosPromo y modificadorID para ModificadorCantidad.
// este es el codigo

```
 List<ProductoResumen> promos = new List<ProductoResumen>();

            ProductoResumen promo = new ProductoResumen();
            promo.ProductoID = 1;
            promo.ProductoNombre = "Papas + Refresco";
            promo.PromocionID = 1;
            promo.Cantidad = 1;

            promo.ProductosPromos = new List<ProductoPromo>()
            {
                new ProductoPromo(){
                    ProductoID = 2,
                    ProductoNombre = "Papas",
                    Cantidad = 1,
                    ModificadorCantidadLista = new List<ModificadorCantidad>(){
                        new ModificadorCantidad(){
                            ModificadorID = 100,
                            Modificador = "Salsa verde",
                            Cantidad =1,
                        },
                        new ModificadorCantidad(){
                            ModificadorID = 110,
                            Modificador = "Crema",
                            Cantidad =1,
                        },
                        new ModificadorCantidad(){
                            ModificadorID = 120,
                            Modificador = "Especias",
                            Cantidad =1,
                        }
                    }
                },
                  new ProductoPromo(){
                    ProductoID = 2,
                    ProductoNombre = "Papas",
                    Cantidad = 1,
                    ModificadorCantidadLista = new List<ModificadorCantidad>(){
                        new ModificadorCantidad(){
                            ModificadorID = 101,
                            Modificador = "Salsa Roja",
                            Cantidad =1,
                        },
                        new ModificadorCantidad(){
                            ModificadorID = 110,
                            Modificador = "Crema",
                            Cantidad =1,
                        },
                        new ModificadorCantidad(){
                            ModificadorID = 120,
                            Modificador = "Especias",
                            Cantidad =1,
                        }
                    }
                },
                 new ProductoPromo(){
                    ProductoID = 3,
                    ProductoNombre = "Coca Cola",
                    Cantidad = 1,
                    ModificadorCantidadLista = new List<ModificadorCantidad>(){
                        new ModificadorCantidad(){
                            ModificadorID = 200,
                            Modificador = "Limon",
                            Cantidad =1,
                        },
                        new ModificadorCantidad(){
                            ModificadorID = 210,
                            Modificador = "Tequila",
                            Cantidad =1,
                        } 
                    }
                },

            };
            promos.Add(promo);

            // buscar
            ProductoResumen Nuevo = new ProductoResumen();
            Nuevo.ProductoID = 1;
            Nuevo.ProductoNombre = "Papas + Refresco";
            Nuevo.PromocionID = 1;
            Nuevo.Cantidad = 1;

            Nuevo.ProductosPromos = new List<ProductoPromo>()
            {
                new ProductoPromo(){
                    ProductoID = 2,
                    ProductoNombre = "Papas",
                    Cantidad = 1,
                    ModificadorCantidadLista = new List<ModificadorCantidad>(){
                        new ModificadorCantidad(){
                            ModificadorID = 100,
                            Modificador = "Salsa verde",
                            Cantidad =1,
                        },
                        new ModificadorCantidad(){
                            ModificadorID = 110,
                            Modificador = "Crema",
                            Cantidad =1,
                        },
                        new ModificadorCantidad(){
                            ModificadorID = 120,
                            Modificador = "Especias",
                            Cantidad =1,
                        }
                    }
                },
                  new ProductoPromo(){
                    ProductoID = 2,
                    ProductoNombre = "Papas",
                    Cantidad = 1,
                    ModificadorCantidadLista = new List<ModificadorCantidad>(){
                        new ModificadorCantidad(){
                            ModificadorID = 101,
                            Modificador = "Salsa Roja",
                            Cantidad =1,
                        },
                        new ModificadorCantidad(){
                            ModificadorID = 110,
                            Modificador = "Crema",
                            Cantidad =1,
                        },
                        new ModificadorCantidad(){
                            ModificadorID = 120,
                            Modificador = "Especias",
                            Cantidad =1,
                        }
                    }
                },
                 new ProductoPromo(){
                    ProductoID = 3,
                    ProductoNombre = "Coca Cola",
                    Cantidad = 1,
                    ModificadorCantidadLista = new List<ModificadorCantidad>(){
                        new ModificadorCantidad(){
                            ModificadorID = 200,
                            Modificador = "Limon",
                            Cantidad =1,
                        },
                        new ModificadorCantidad(){
                            ModificadorID = 210,
                            Modificador = "Tequila",
                            Cantidad =1,
                        }
                    }
                },

            };

            //var result = items.Where(d => !existe.Select(x => x.JMPMD_ModificadorID).Contains(d.JMPMD_ModificadorID)).ToList();

            var Existe = promos.Where(p => p.ProductoID == Nuevo.ProductoID)                                
                                .Where(prod => 
                                    prod.ProductosPromos
                                    .All(p => 
                                        Nuevo.ProductosPromos.Exists(e =>
                                            e.ProductoID == p.ProductoID
                                            &&
                                            prod.ModificadorCantidadLista
                                                .All(c => 
                                                    e.ModificadorCantidadLista
                                                    .Exists(m3=> m3.ModificadorID == c.ModificadorID)
                                                )
                                        )                                       
                                    )
                                ).FirstOrDefault();


            if (Existe != null)
            {

            }
```

en si me encuentra al objeto, pero si cambio por lo menos el id de un modificador o el de un productoId, este deberia de mandarme null la variable Existe, pero siempre me manda que lo encuentra a pesar de que todas las ModificadoresId no coinciden.
alguna idea?

Comment: Podrías explicar mejor lo que tratas de hacer, y si gustas agregar las clases que usas.

Comment: Editado... basicamente quiero tomar el objeto ProductosResumen si coincide en ProductoID y modificadoresID, si tienen los mismos ID

Comment: Estoy revisando, he cambiado el ProductoId del nuevo ProductoResumen, si me ha funcionado.

Comment: pero seria tambien en modificadorID, al no tener id similares deberia de lanzar nullo